# Passing page number param for infinite-scroll to return more results from the backend

Tags: angularjs

I'm using [infinite-scroll](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/index.html) and I want to request more data using $http.  So next page / next 10 results etc.

This is my current working code (I put this in a factory as I read on another post somewhere that this was a good idea, I'm now thinking a service might be better but I'm not sure yet):

```
    angular.module('hotels', [])

    .factory('hotels', function($http) {
      var hotels = {};
      hotels.get = function(callback) {
        $http.get('/php/hotels.php').success(function(data) {
          callback(data);
        });
      };
      return hotels;
    });

    angular.module('app', ['hotels', 'infinite-scroll'])

    .controller('hotelsCtrl', function ($scope, hotels){

        hotels.get(function (data) {
          $scope.hotels = data.results;
        })
    });
```

How do I pass back a param `page=3` and have the backend return more results?

I thought it might look something like this but its not working.:

```
    angular.module('hotels', [])

    .factory('hotels', function($http) {
      var hotels = {};
      hotels.get = function(callback) {
        $http.get('/php/hotels.php?page='+$scope.page).success(function(data) {
          callback(data);
        });
      };
      return hotels;
    });

    angular.module('app', ['hotels', 'infinite-scroll'])


    .controller('hotelsCtrl', function ($scope, hotels){
        $scope.page = $scope.page + 1;

        hotels.get({page: $scope.page}, function (data) {
          $scope.hotels.push.apply($scope.hotels, data.results);
        })

    });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need a scope function, to call the new items to be pushed, i.e. $scope.getHotels = hotels.get(... 
I am not familiar with infinite scroll in angular, how is it trigured? shouldn't you be using it in your controller to call new items?

Comment: Yeah I would need a `$scope.getHotels()` function which is triggered within a directive `<ul infinite-scroll="addMoreItems()" infinite-scroll-distance="3">` ..... I get a $scope not defined error when trying that though.

Comment: You are not supposed to use it as $scope.getHotels(), just getHotels() should do it. Scope is only used inside your controller

Comment: I think I'm a bit lost with this, would you mind giving me a code example?

Comment: Looks like I'm getting somewhere now :)

Answer (score 0):

This does the job:

```
    angular.module('hotels', [])

    .factory('hotels', function($http) {
      var hotels = {};
      hotels.get = function(params, callback) {
        $http.get('/php/hotels.php', {params: {page: params.page}}).success(function(data) {
          callback(data);
        });
      };
      return hotels;
    });

    angular.module('app', ['hotels', 'infinite-scroll'])


    .controller('hotelsCtrl', function ($scope, hotels){
       $scope.page = 1;

      $scope.addMoreItems = function() {
        $scope.hotels=[];

        hotels.get({page: $scope.page}, function (data) {
          //$scope.hotels.push(data.results);
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $scope.hotels.push(data[i]);
          }
          $scope.page+=1;
        })
      }

    });
```